# Происхождение фразеологизма "бежать со всех ног"

Tags: фразеология

Значение фразеологизма понятно, но не очень ясна его структура.

Откуда здесь **родительный падеж с предлогом СО**? И что означает "**всех**"? Со всех, что есть: с двух, с четырех? Или еще что-то?

Answer (score 2):

Фразеологизмом назвать можно только с большой натяжкой, из-за слова "всех".  Остальное вполне прозрачно, С/СО имел (и не потерял) значение исходного состояния, источника действия.

> _1. кого-чего. Указывает на место, предмет, лицо, явление и т.п., откуда 
>   направлено движение или действие. Спуститься с горы. Приехать с
>   Урала. Пришелец с другой планеты. Сойти с крыльца. Спрыгнуть с коня.
>   Убрать чашку со стола. Сорвать цветок с клумбы. Свернуть с дороги.
>   Прийти с улицы. Вход со двора. Войти в дом с мороза. Порхать с цветка
>   на цветок. Вернуться с концерта. Уволить с работы. Улыбка сошла с
>   лица. Вертеться с боку на бок. Сбыть с рук. Сбиться с ног. Сжить со
>   свету. * Пушки с пристани палят, Кораблю пристать велят (Пушкин). Рыба
>   гниёт с головы (Посл.). С миру по нитке - голому рубаха (Посл.).
>
> _8. кого-чего. Указывает на причину, основание, источник какого-л. 
>   действия, состояния. Устать с дороги. Умереть с голоду. Сделать что-л.
>   со зла. Сгореть со стыда. Покатиться со смеху. Беситься с жиру.
>   Разозлиться ни с того ни с сего. Напечатать интервью с согласия
>   автора. Жениться с благословения родителей. Красный с мороза. Трудно с
>   непривычки. Критиковать с позиций материализма.

(Кузнецов)
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81&all=x

Сравните еще "*сбился с ног*".

"Всех" может означать наибольшую полноту действия.
Сравните: *со всей силы*, *со всего маху* и даже *со всей дури*.

В варианте ["падать со всех ног"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3) прослеживается и прямое на то указание - народ падал со всех ног, никто не оставался на ногах (при появлении царя).

Comment: @Sibylla спасибо за мнение.  Хотелось бы конкретики. В вашем ответе, кстати, нет рассмотрения "связи".

Answer (score 1):

> Фразеологизм здесь только "со всех ног", он сочетается со всеми
>   глаголами быстрого движения: бежать, мчаться, нестись,
>   броситься,кинуться, растянуться и т.д.
>
> Многие лингвисты считают, что он заимствован из франц. языка в виде
>   кальки: a toutes jambes. Первоначально о лошадях, оборот появился в
>   результате наблюдений за аллюром лошадей.

[СО ВСЕХ НОГ | biblioclub.ru](http://enc.biblioclub.ru/Termin/1833203_SO_VSEH_NOG)

Другие утверждают, что это восточнославянский фразеологизм, т.к. выражение существует в русском, белорусском и украинском языках и их диалектах.

Фразеологизм "со всех ног"(бежать)  широко представлен в сказках: дурак со всех ног побежал туда; медведь бросился со всех ног; чертенок … со всех ног махнул из-за печки вон; (волки) со всех ног припустили бежать без оглядки; медведь со всех ног пустился бежать; дурак … бежит со всех ног;бросилась девка со всех ног; заяц со всех ног пустился бежать. Есть два примера, показывающие пути дальнейшего развития ФЕ и, таким образом, указывающие на достаточный срок еѐ существования: Съел одну ягодку – вдруг ударило его со всех ног о сырую землю, и сделался он жеребцом ; бросилась она (кошка) туда со всех четырех ног.

Находим аналогичные примеры и в художественной литературе, но и здесь они, вероятно, носят диалектный характер: …Саша догнал его, толкнул в спину, и мальчишка упал со всех ног (А. Пушкин. Дубровский); Разгонись я за тем зайцем, конь посклизнулся, вдарился со всехног и головы не приподнял (М. Шолохов. Тихий Дон).

В ХVIII веке данная ФЕ отмечается со значением "очень сильно (удариться, упасть)"  М. Ф. Палевская указывает, что «у ФЕ со всех ног наметилось развитие значения сильно, но оно так и не закрепилось за данной ФЕ»].

В. И. Даль толкует лексему "растянуться" как "упасть со всех ног", т. е. интересующим нас оборотом. Н. П. Макаров в своѐм известном словаре переводит оборот упасть со всех ног на французский язык как tomberdesonhaut, т.е. «растянуться во весь рост». Рассматриваемая фразеологическая единица подтверждает общую тенденцию движения такого рода оборотов от конкретного к абстрактному, от образного к  безОбразному.

Фразеологический словарь Захаренко даёт культурологический комментарий: "фразеол. восходит к древнейшим формам осознания мира и соотносится с соматическим (телесным) кодом культуры. Данная метафора отображает  стереотипное представление (создающееся за счёт компонента всех) о максимальной степени проявления признака, присущего описываемому действию, - в данном случае о быстроте и стремительности движения (ср. также смотреть во все глаза, мастер на все руки и под.). В целом фразеол. выполняет роль эталона, т. е. меры, быстроты действия человека при перемещении в пространстве. В других европейских языках есть сходные образные выражения; напр., в англ. - as smb."s legs will carry him, во франц. - à toutes jambes.

Таким образом, структура сращения "со всех ног" действительно иногда выглядит странновато (упал со всех ног), но если иметь в виду, что это калька и первоначально относилось к лошадям, то всё нормально.

Answer (score -2):

Да, значит, наши предки "**падали  со всех ног**", отсюда и "все ноги", и предлог СО.

Получается, что правилен был ответ, которому я сначала не очень поверила (привожу его полностью, теперь он мне нравится.):

[Что означает выражение: "бежать со всех ног"? | bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/272747-chto-oznachaet-vyrazhenie-bezhat-so-vseh-nog.html)

"Собственно в выражении "бежать со всех ног" подвох закрался  в невпопад добавленном туда в конце XIX века слове "**бежать**", до этого времени **фразеологизм был короче  (со всех ног**) и означал скорое и одномоментное преклонение колен всеми присутствующими, вне зависимости от чинов и званий.
В веке ХХ такие сцены, как одномоментное коленопреклонение, описывать перестали, а к **старому выражению, означающему большой душевный порыв и единение, прилепили слово "бежать"**, и теперь "бежать со всех ног" значит "бежать изо всех сил", "бежать не жалея ног", "бежать очень быстро".

Кстати, **можно сравнить этот оригинальный  и точный ответ** с другими, в которых отвечающие больше фантазируют, чем говорят по делу.

В ответе на "Большом вопросе" (а это совсем не сомнительный, а очень известный ресурс, но интересных вопросов именно по русскому языку там бывает мало) не хватало цитаты вроде этой: "Предки наши падали со всех ног, увидя государя. И. М. Долгоруков, 1788—1822 г. Поэтому информация мне показалось недостоверной. А теперь всё сошлось: цитата и тот ответ. Получается, что фразеологизм "падать со всех ног" имел дословное значение - вот что интересно, а "бежать со всех ног" - это более позднее выражение.

Comment: Мимоходов (пока единственный ответивший) говорит вполне по делу.

Comment: @shampar, ну Sibylla же лучше знает, как на её вопрос надо отвечать. ))) Но сравнить действительно можете. Если найдете, чем принципиально противоречу - дайте знать. Единственная новация там - заявление о том, что исходная форма была короче: "со всех ног". Но это весьма спорно  ибо без какого-то глагола она совершенно не смотрится.  При этом ответ мой - практически экспромт, мелкие же шероховатости вполне возможны, но даже и их-то нет.

Comment: А вообще мне нравится этот подход ))). Находится на каком-то сомнительном ресурсе вопрос и ответ к нему, а потом выдается за иистину в последней инстанции.

Comment: Известность ресурса никоим образом не свидетельствует о его авторитетности. Обычная помойка.

Comment: @Sibylla "наш" ресурс не является авторитетным, поскольку мнения здесь приводятся различные и часто друг другу противоречащие. Вы можете пользоваться всем чем угодно отсюда, но под собственную ответственность, не выдавая за априорную истину. Интернет так устроен.

Comment: Очень много информации не относится к вопросу, также не показан ясно переход от "падать со всех ног" к "бежать со всех ног". Второй минус - мой.